# WPF Change DataGrid Cell Style dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have two cell template, one is for "ReadOnly" the other is for "CellEditing".
And a button is binding a command to switch a variable (IsEditable) to be true/false.
When I click the button, the style does not change until double click the cell.

My question is, how to change DataGrid Cell Style dynamically without double click the cell.

My XAML:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ReadOnlyTemplate">
  <TextBox Text="{Binding ProductionName}">
    <TextBox.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
      </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
  </TextBox>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="CellEditingTemplate">
  <TextBox Text="{Binding ProductionName}">
    <TextBox.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEditable}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
          </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
  </TextBox>
</DataTemplate>

...

<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" CellTemplate="{StaticResource ReadOnlyTemplate}" CellEditingTemplate="{StaticResource CellEditingTemplate}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

CellEditingTemplate is only applied when you already edit the cell. What you want is to modify the style while you are not editing.
Try this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ProductionNameTemplate" >
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ProductionName}">
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEditable}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

And apply this as CellTemplate.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" CellTemplate="{StaticResource ProductionNameTemplate}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it is no different. I still need to double click the cell to change style.

Comment: That's strange because I have used similar code some time ago and know that it works. Besides that, you shouldn't be able to edit the cell at all when you set `IsEditbale` to false.
Are you sure that your Binding is ok? Have you checked the output window if it shows Binding error messages?
I also don't understand why the cell is changed when you start to edit while using the code above. When `CellEditingTemplate` is not set, nothing should change when you edit.

Comment: If your Binding is not ok, try this: `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Value="True">`

Comment: If `IsEditable` is false then I can not edit the cell. If `IsEditable` is true, I can edit the cell with double click.

Comment: Then the Binding is ok and it also shows that the Style is working and that it sets the `IsEnabled` property of the TextBox to false. But in that case, the properties `Background` and `Foreground` should be changed as well. Have you really removed the `CellEditingTemplate` from your 
`DataGridTemplateColumn` or is there another style applied?